# Does this similarity measure have a name?

Tags: similarities, divergence

Consider two probability distributions P and Q defined on the same probability space X. Does the following similarity measure have a name?

[image]

**Context:** I "invented" this formula to compare binding-sequence statistics of proteins and would like to check the validity of this approach and read up on alternatives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what this is called, but to me it looks like your expression is related to the hellinger distance H(P, Q) via $$\mathrm{similarity(P, Q)} = 1-H^2(P, Q)$$.

Maybe this will help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hellinger_distance#Discrete_distributions

Comment: Note the name is on that page (although the formula is not as obvious on that page is it perhaps should be). It is the [Bhattacharyya Coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhattacharyya_distance#Bhattacharyya_coefficient).

Comment: Bhattacharyya Coefficient - That's it! Very helpful!